# Delete the second to last line of a json file

Tags: c++, json, qt

I am trying to write user inputs into a json file. My issue is in maintaining valid json. Every time I write new data to my file I need to delete a closing square bracket "]" which is on the second to last line of my file. I'm still new to C++ and not sure how to do this. I changed the file outputs for the sake of reading but normally I have variable holding user input values.

```cpp
makefile(){      
    std::ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("data.json");
    if(!ifile)
    {
        std::ofstream file("data.json");
        file << "\n{\n\"IO Inputs \"" <<  ":"   << " \n[\n";     
        file.close();

    }
    else {
        std::fstream file;
        file.open("data.json", std::ios_base::app);
        if (file.is_open())
             file << "\n{\n";
        file.close();
    }


}
write() {
   std::fstream file;
   file.open("data.json", std::ios_base::app);
   if (file.is_open())
   file << "{\"tag\" " << ": " <<11 << ",\n";
   file << "\"disp\" " << ": " <<12 << ",\n";
   file << "\"mnemonic\"" << ":\"" <<"some string" << "\",\n";
   file << "\"iotype\" " << ": " << true << "\n";
   file << "]\n}\n";
   file.close();
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Use a JSON library to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Very hard to say how to do this without seeing the rest of your code, and a sample of the data you are trying to change. You won't be surprised to know that there is no magic delete second last line of a file function in C++.

Comment: My suggestion is to create one `map (std::map)` if you didn't want to use JSON libs, then you **can easily update** it and after that save it in the file. although qt has good classes for working with JSON

Answer (score 0):

For example, write data in JSON format:

**This code do this** :

```
 QFile  dat("tmp.json");

 dat.resize(0);

 QString str = "how are you do";
 QJsonDocument  doc;
 QJsonObject    obj;

 obj["tempText"] = str;

 doc.setObject(obj);
 QByteArray  data_json = doc.toJson();

 if (dat.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
 {
    dat.write(data_json);
    dat.flush();
    dat.close();
 }
```

and the output is like this in `tmp.json` file :

```
{
"tempText": "how are you do"
}
```

As you see you need to update `QJsonObject` each time. I **didn't** add `{}` **manually**.

please read [QJsonDocument **toJson** function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsondocument.html#toJson)

**For more info read:**

[QJsonArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html) and [JSON Support in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/json.html)

Comment: Hi Parisa, QJsonobject does great for making valid Json like you show. However it doesn't seem like there is any good way to make a new QJsonobject without hard coding it. I need to take 4 user inputs and make a new object every time I press save on my GUI.

Comment: @DanielPadula so you can have QJsonArray and each time you create an object add it to QJsonArray.

Comment: Right, I think the array is the best solution as well.  But my issue I guess now would be not knowing how to create a new object for each time I hit my "save" button.

Comment: @DanielPadula  watch this video please I think it do what you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCZ5z819znE&t=624s